# How control bandwidth with mikrotik queue

Tags: mikrotik

I have a mikrotik router and i want to limit the speed of wlan users. I create a queue for target = wlan and set the limit downloa and upload = 64k, but when i test it, this seems not working correctly! 
Test download speed > 500k.
The router config is default.
How can i do that

```
/interface bridge
add admin-mac=E4:8D:8C:46:C7:0F auto-mac=no comment=defconf name=bridge
/interface wireless
set [ find default-name=wlan1 ] band=2ghz-b/g/n channel-width=20/40mhz-Ce \
    disabled=no distance=indoors frequency=auto mode=ap-bridge ssid=PNG1 \
    wireless-protocol=802.11
/interface ethernet
set [ find default-name=ether2 ] name=ether2-master
set [ find default-name=ether3 ] master-port=ether2-master
set [ find default-name=ether4 ] master-port=ether2-master
set [ find default-name=ether5 ] master-port=ether2-master
/ip neighbor discovery
set ether1 discover=no
set bridge comment=defconf
/interface wireless security-profiles
set [ find default=yes ] authentication-types=wpa-psk,wpa2-psk mode=\
    dynamic-keys wpa-pre-shared-key=noor3664 wpa2-pre-shared-key=noor3664
/ip hotspot profile
add dns-name=so.zzz hotspot-address=10.5.50.1 login-by=http-pap name=hsprof1 \
    use-radius=yes
/ip pool
add name=dhcp ranges=192.168.88.10-192.168.88.254
add name=hs-pool-2 ranges=10.5.50.2-10.5.50.254
/ip dhcp-server
add address-pool=dhcp authoritative=after-10sec-delay disabled=no interface=\
    bridge name=defconf
add address-pool=hs-pool-2 interface=ether2-master lease-time=1h name=dhcp1
/ip hotspot
add address-pool=hs-pool-2 addresses-per-mac=1 interface=ether2-master name=\
    hotspot1 profile=hsprof1
/ip hotspot user profile
add address-pool=hs-pool-2 advertise=yes advertise-interval="" advertise-url="" \
    name=uprof1 open-status-page=http-login transparent-proxy=yes
/queue type
set 0 pfifo-limit=200
/queue interface
set ether2-master queue=default-small
/queue simple
add limit-at=30k/30k max-limit=30k/30k name=queue1 queue=default/default \
    target=bridge total-queue=default
/interface bridge port
add bridge=bridge comment=defconf interface=ether2-master
add auto-isolate=yes bridge=bridge interface=wlan1
/ip address
add address=192.168.88.1/24 comment=defconf interface=bridge network=\
    192.168.88.0
add address=10.5.50.1/24 comment="hotspot network" interface=ether2-master \
    network=10.5.50.0
/ip dhcp-client
add comment=defconf dhcp-options=hostname,clientid disabled=no interface=ether1
/ip dhcp-server network
add address=10.5.50.0/24 comment="hotspot network" gateway=10.5.50.1
add address=192.168.88.0/24 comment=defconf gateway=192.168.88.1
/ip dns
set allow-remote-requests=yes servers=4.2.2.4
/ip dns static
add address=10.5.50.1 name=router
/ip firewall filter
add chain=input comment="defconf: accept ICMP" protocol=icmp
add chain=input comment="defconf: accept established,related" connection-state=\
    established,related
add action=drop chain=input comment="defconf: drop all from WAN" in-interface=\
    ether1
add action=fasttrack-connection chain=forward comment="defconf: fasttrack" \
    connection-state=established,related
add chain=forward comment="defconf: accept established,related" \
    connection-state=established,related
add action=drop chain=forward comment="defconf: drop invalid" connection-state=\
    invalid
add action=drop chain=forward comment=\
    "defconf:  drop all from WAN not DSTNATed" connection-nat-state=!dstnat \
    connection-state=new in-interface=ether1
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="defconf: masquerade" out-interface=\
    ether1
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="masquerade hotspot net
    src-address=10.5.50.0/24
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="masquerade hotspot net
    src-address=10.5.50.0/24
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="masquerade hotspot net
    src-address=10.5.50.0/24
/ip hotspot user
add name=admin
/radius
add address=192.168.88.1 service=hotspot
add address=192.168.88.1 service=hotspot
/system clock
set time-zone-name=Asia/Tehran
/system leds
set 0 interface=wlan1
/system routerboard settings
set protected-routerboot=disabled
/tool mac-server
set [ find default=yes ] disabled=yes
add interface=bridge
/tool mac-server mac-winbox
set [ find default=yes ] disabled=yes
add interface=bridge
[admin@MikroTik] >
```

Comment: Did you read through any of the plenty of tutorials on the mikrotik site?

Comment: yes, i add the export.

Answer (score 1):

Disable any fasttrack rules on your firewall.

Fasttrack will bypass pretty much the whole stack - including the queues.

It's mentioned very clearly in the documentation.
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Wiki/Fasttrack

> Description
>
> IPv4 FastTrack handler is automatically used for marked connections.
>   Use firewall action "fasttrack-connection" to mark connections for
>   fasttrack. Currently only TCP and UDP connections can be actually
>   fasttracked (even though any connection can be marked for fasttrack).
>   IPv4 FastTrack handler supports NAT (SNAT, DNAT or both).
>
> Note that not all packets in a connection can be fasttracked, so it is
>   likely to see some packets going through slow path even though
>   connection is marked for fasttrack. This is the reason why
>   fasttrack-connection is usually followed be identical action=accept
>   rule. **Fasttracked packets bypass firewall, connection tracking,
>   simple queues, queue tree with parent=global, ip
>   traffic-flow(restriction removed in 6.33), ip accounting, ipsec,
>   hotspot universal client, vrf assignment, so it is up to administrator
>   to make sure fasttrack does not interfere with other configuration;**

Answer (score 0):

You need simple queue with PCQ in order to control all (or specific range) users bandwidth. following are one example:

```
/ip firewall address-list
add address=10.0.0.20-10.0.0.255 list=USER_LIST

# Marking packets going to USER_LIST
/ip firewall mangle
add action=mark-connection chain=prerouting comment="MARK CONN USER_LIST" src-address-list=USER_LIST new-connection-mark=user_conn passthrough=yes
add action=mark-packet chain=prerouting comment="MARK PKTS USER_LIST" connection-mark=user_conn new-packet-mark=user_pkts passthrough=yes

# Creating PCQ base Queue - 512k per user
/queue type
add kind=pcq name=user-download-512k pcq-classifier=dst-address pcq-dst-address6-mask=64 pcq-rate=512k pcq-src-address6-mask=64
add kind=pcq name=user-upload-512k pcq-classifier=src-address pcq-dst-address6-mask=64 pcq-rate=512k pcq-src-address6-mask=64

#- Make sure you move this simple queue on TOP, or else it will not work
/queue simple
add comment="Allow 512k Down/up per user by zaib" name="512k per user" packet-marks=user_pkts queue=user-upload-512k/user-download-512k target=""
```

More Info here.[queue example](https://aacable.wordpress.com/tag/dynamic-queues/)